# Не работает сравнение с Null

Tags: delphi, отладка, null

Есть строки кода (см. рис.):

1. `KeyValue = null` (я знаю, что там должен быть "null", так пишет и debbuger), но почему-то программа в упор считает наоборот, и идет в "*else*".
2. и почему в debbuger - `dblcbNameOrganizationProposal.KeyValue = Null` - не допустимое выражение?

P.S. Оптимизатор выключен

[image: lphi]

Comment: А какой тип у `KeyValue`?

Comment: Есть дикое предположение, что `FMain <> Self`. Попробуйте убрать FMain из условия, оставив только dblcb....

Comment: @zed  "KeyValue" = integer. (showmessage('not null = '+inttostr(FMain.dblcbNameOrganizationProposal.KeyValue));)

Comment: @kami  убрал "FMain" - не помогло

Comment: А если запускать просто "Run without debugging" - то все нормально отрабатывает

Comment: Я что то упустил? или в делфи появился `null` не для `Variant`? Для остальных типов всегда был `nil` =)

Answer (score 1):

Предложили воспользоваться функцией "**VarIsNull**" - вот она отрабатывает нормально.
Кстати и в окне debbuger'а она показывает результат, а не "*Expression illegal in evaluator*"

Comment: В Delphi `Null` - это не константа, а функция. Она каждый раз возвращает новый экземпляр переменной типа `Variant`, инициализированный `Null`'ом.